# Conseguir o ID de uma linha de uma consulta de Gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Fiz uma consulta em que é populado uma gridview, as colunas são codigo, categoria, noprazo, foradoprazo. Nas colunas noprazo e foradoprazo, deixei-as como `linkbuttom` que ao clicar na linha do item resultante ou de noprazo ou fora do prazo, me retorna o ID da linha clicada.

Isto é executado no `GridView1_RowCommand` como segue abaixo, Mas não me retorna o id da linha clicada.

O que devo fazer?

```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Detalhar")
        {

            chamadosEntities carga1 = new chamadosEntities();
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridView1.SelectedIndex = index;
            int codigoId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja um exemplo abaixo.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Detalhar")
        {

            chamadosEntities carga1 = new chamadosEntities();
            ButtonCommand Btn = new ButtonCommand(sender);
            int index = Btn.ArgumentAsInt;


            GridView1.SelectedIndex = index;
            int codigoId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);





   public class ButtonCommand
    {
        private IButtonControl m_Btn = null;

        public ButtonCommand(object sender)
        {
            m_Btn = sender as IButtonControl;
            if (m_Btn == null)
                throw new Exception("sender não é IButtonControl");
        }


        public Int32 ArgumentAsInt
        {
            get
            {
                Int32 Result = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(m_Btn.CommandArgument, out Result);
                return Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: acredito que a linha : int codigoId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value); posssa ser substituida  por <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="codigoId "> e no codo behind    Int32 codigoId = (Int32)Grid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;

Comment: Vlw Marconcilio , deu certo... Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Veja se este exemplo serve:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      if (e.CommandName.Equals("Detalhar"))
      {
        carga1.Id = Convert.ToInt32(this.GridView1.DataKeys[id]["ID"]);

        this.GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        this.GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        Session.Add("SESSAO", carga1);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      Show("Não foi possível realizar a operação.");
    }
  }
```